# An Adjective for being happy vs an adjective to being happy

Tags: prepositions

I am wondering which one of those are right in the case of the given dialogue or if both of them are so but with a slight difference in meaning.

*It's an Adjective for being happy.*

*It's an adjective to being happy.*

Dialogue:

Speaker A: What does merry mean here? I thought it was an adjective!

Speaker B: Actually it *is* an adjective and it means happy.

Speaker A: I understand that it's an adjective for being happy but look it functions as an adverb in that sentence. Maybe it means sth else here.

By the way I know that without 'being' only the first sentence would sound good but I wonder if with being that would change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an adjective that means happy.

Typically, that's what one would say.

X is a y that means z.

Comment: So the clause still can't make any sense even in the case of that dialogue?

Comment: I understand that it's an adjective that means happy but, look, it functions as an adverb in that sentence. [or this, I don't know].